# How to make domain authentication with linux server and windows clients?

Tags: windows, linux, domain

I want to make "desktop logon authentication system" for a large number of windows clients with a linux domain server. I have a dns server (bind9 on linux) and but not yet any kind of ldap system or server. Is it possible to make something like that? and What kind of softwares and hardwares should I possess?

Answer (score 4):

Samba.  http://www.samba.org

You don't mention what version clients you have, and that may affect what version you need to use.

Comment: clients are at least and mostly windows xp, some windows 7 and small amount linux clients. but what I want is  not any kind of directory or print services. only authenticate users (students) those using lab computers.

Comment: then you want samba as pdc :)